# Display ng-model item.value as item.value.text inside select

Tags: angularjs

I have the following `select`

```
<select ng-change="onChange(item)" ng-model="item.Probability" ng-options="item as item.text for item in Probability">
</select>
```

I can select from different items inside an array called `Probability`.

Probability:

```
$scope.Probability = [{text: '', value: },
```

The item is displayed to the user as `item.text`, but is saved in ng-model as just item (as you can see in my select)

When I want to edit this item (sometime after it is saved), I would like to display Probability.text as already chosen inside the select, but since the model is set to Probability (with .value and .text) my select is just blank.

How can I display `item.Probability` as `item.Probability.text`, and writing it like that inside the model did not work.

Answer (score 0):

`<select ng-change="onChange(item)" ng-model="item.Probability" ng-options="item.value as item.text for item in Probability">
  <option value="">What's your probability</option>
</select>`

in this way, `$scope.item.Probability` would equal to the `item.value` you select

Comment: but, the `<option>` is optional, just for wording, FYI :)

Comment: `<strong>{{Probability[item.value]}}</strong>`

Comment: what does this mean? Where should I use the [item.value], inside ng-model?

Answer (score 0):

This did not work:

```
<select ng-change="onChange(item)" ng-model="item.Probability" ng-options="item as item.text for item in Probability">
</select>
```

But this did:

```
<select ng-change="change(item, editable.ID)" ng-model="item.Probability" ng-options="item as item.text for item in Probability">
    <option style="display:none" value="" disabled>{{item.Probability.text}}</option>
</select>
```

This will put an extra option ontop of my `Probability` options, this option is shown like 'item.probability.text', but doesn't have a value, hence it's disabled. But it shows the user what the value currently is.